# Find all disjointed intersections in a set of vertical line segments

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

I have a set of vertical regions defined by y1 and y2 coordinates, where y1 is the starting point and y2 is the ending point of each region. Origin of my coordinates system is the top-left corner, so y2 is always greater than y1.

This is an example:

```
var regions = [
  [10, 100],
  [50, 120],
  [60, 180],
  [140, 220]
];
```

I would like to find out all disjointed intersections greater than a certain size, let say, for example, 20 units.

Until now I'm only able to get all intersections: `[50, 100],[60, 100],[60, 120],[140, 180]` but I'm expecting this result: `[60, 100],[140, 180]`.
Is there any algorithm to get this result?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4v5qnex5/

Comment: I did not understand what you mean `disjointed intersection` here, and how `[60, 100]` is better than `[50, 100]`

Comment: [60,100] is the intersection among the first three regions, and the  intersection between [60,100] and [140,180] is empty, so they are disjoint.

Comment: I noticed that [60,100] has the largest covering count, but you did not mention importance of this fact. So you implied this criteria but did not not described it. Please, specify the problem better. I suspect that different criteria might come into contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question is clear. It requests the *disjointed intersections* in a given array of vertical edge ranges. Which means

```
[[10, 100], [50, 120], [60, 180], [140, 220]]
```

array gives us two disjointed intersection one being from `[10, 100], [50, 120], [60, 180]` and resulting `[60,100]` and the other being from `[60, 180], [140, 220]]` and resulting `[140,180]`. So as you notice the resulting intersections `[60,100]` and `[140,180]` those obtained from this given set of vertical edges are disjointed.

One way of implementing this functionality in JS is as follows;

```js
function getDisjointedIntersections(a){
  var di;
  return a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c.used ? p
                                      : (p.push(a.map((_,j) => a[(i+j)%a.length])
                                                 .reduce((s,e) =>  (di = [Math.max(s[0],e[0]), Math.min(s[1],e[1])],
                                                                    di[0] < di[1] ? (e.used = true, di) : s))),p),[]);
}

var regions = [[10, 100],[50, 120],[60, 180],[140, 220],[150, 330]];
console.log(getDisjointedIntersections(regions));
```

**Explanation:** At first it's easy to perceive the job as a simple reducing job but i guess it is not. There are cases you that you should consider the previous vertical edges so multiple passes might be required.

So we will start with the given array and start reducing our vertical edges into their intersection as much as we can. While doing so every vertical edge that results a successful intersection will be assigned a property named `used` with value `true`. Once this pass is finished we will rotate our input array up until an unused vertical edge comes to index position 0 and start reducing the vertical edges by intersection again but this time from an item that was not used previously.

So the heart of the code, the intersection reducer is

```
.reduce((s,e) =>  (di = [Math.max(s[0],e[0]), Math.min(s[1],e[1])],
                   di[0] < di[1] ? (e.used = true, di) : s))
```

This is a simple reduce without an initial. It first assigns the intersection to `di`.

```
di = [Math.max(s[0],e[0]), Math.min(s[1],e[1])]
```

and then if the intersection is successful then it marks the current element as used and returns `di` which will be the previous element of the next reduce cycle. If the intersection is not successful then it will return the previous intersection to the next reduce cycle.

```
di[0] < di[1] ? (e.used = true, di) : s))
```

Ok we have finished a cycle and only `[10, 100], [50, 120], [60, 180]` have intersected and resulted `[60,100]`. So we push this result to the outer reduces initial array.

```
(p.push(a.map((_,j) => a[(i+j)%a.length])
         .reduce((s,e) => ... // the code that we already know
```

But what is the map function that we chained our reduce to. The map is rotating our input array by one index per the iteration of the outer reduce. OK have a look at it and you will understand how it does it's job

```
a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c.used ? p
                             : (p.push(a.map((_,j) => a[(i+j)%a.length])
                                 .redu...
```

But as you will also notice we are not making wasteful rotations. We first wait until our outer reduce's current element (`c`) meets an unused item. Only then we rotate the input array to form up our new input array. For instance the two input arrays that we have to work on this example are.

```
[ [ 10, 100 ],[ 50, 120 ],[ 60, 180 ],[ 140, 220 ],[ 150, 330 ] ]
```

and

```
[ [ 140, 220 ],[ 150, 330 ],[ 10, 100, used: true ],[ 50, 120, used: true ],[ 60, 180, used: true ] ]
```

So in this particular case just two passes marks all vertical edges as used and gives us all two disconnected intersections... regardless how many times you shuffle the input array.

It calculates a 1000 item input data in 15~16msecs and 10000 item data in about 400-500msecs. You may check the code and play with the parameters [here](https://repl.it/EKZf)

OK the following version is modified to show only the allowed size disjointed intersections. You might like to try [here](https://repl.it/EKZf/1) for different number of vertical edges, axis sizes, and minimum size of disjointed intersections.

```js
function getDisjointedIntersections(a,n){
  var di,                                  // disjointed intersections
      ri;                                  // resulting intersections
  return a.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
                    if (c.used) return p;
                    ri = a.map((_,j) => a[(i+j)%a.length])
                          .reduce(function(s,e){
                                    di = [Math.max(s[0],e[0]), Math.min(s[1],e[1])];
                                    return di[0] < di[1] ? (e.used = true, di) : s;
                                  });
                    ri[1] - ri[0] > n && p.push(ri);
                    return p;
                  },[]);
}

var regions = [[10, 100],[50, 120],[60, 180],[140, 220],[150, 330]];
console.log(getDisjointedIntersections(regions,20));
```

Comment: I'm doing me hard with your piece of code, some comments would be useful for me, as i can't copy & paste your solution as-is...could you please kindly help me to understand the algorithm?

Comment: @deblocker Ok i have added some explanation. I hope it helps you. There might be some better ways but this is what i could have come up with late yesterday night.

Comment: THX, i guess intersections smaller than a given size could be filtered out before the push to the outer reduces array, thus avoiding the extra final pass over all returned intersections. You agree?

Comment: @deblocker All right, we don't need to attach a filter to the output. It can nicely be filtered with a small change. I have refactored the code, into a more conventional one and included at the end of my answer. I am pretty sure you can understand better this way.

Answer (score 0):

As @MBo says there doesn't seem to be a clear reason for choosing the intersections `[60, 100],[140, 180]` as all intersections (`[50, 100],[60, 100],[60, 120],[140, 180]`) are clearly more than 20. But if for some reason you're still wanting to get intersections greater than a certain size here's a procedure:

```
sort regions by the lower bound of each element
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    for (j = i+1; j < len; j++)
        if the ith and jth region overlap and resultingSize > theSizeYouWant
            add to the list of valid intersections // or whatever you want
        else break
```

where `len` is the length of `regions`(so in the example you gave `len = 4`). Here's some python that does the above (it's the simplest way I know to sort by an index for a group of lists)

```python
from operator import itemgetter
regions = [
  [10, 100],
  [50, 120],
  [60, 180],
  [140, 220]
]   

# sort regions by the lower bound of each element
# (already done in your test case)
regions = sorted(regions, key=itemgetter(0))

# the size to compare to
size = 20

# list of valid intersections
l = []

# for (i = 0; i < len(regions)-1; i++)
for i in range(len(regions)-1):
    # for (j = i; j < len(regions)-1; j++)
    for j in range(i+1,len(regions)):
        # make sure regions overlap and if they do that they are at least size
        if (regions[i][1]>regions[j][0] and regions[i][1]-regions[j][0]>size):
            # add intersection to l
            l.append(str(regions[j][0])+"-"+str(regions[i][1]))
        # if not then there's no need to look at the others
        else:
            break

# print list of valid intersections
print(l)
```

Output:

`['50-100', '60-100', '60-120', '140-180']`

For a different input of

```
regions = [
  [70, 100],
  [50, 120],
  [80, 180],
  [150, 220]
]
```

Output:

`['70-120', '80-120', '150-180']`

I apologize if this is the trivial thing that you have already done, but maybe there's something somewhat useful...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simplified algorithm and use a cross product for searching for overlapping items. Then get the common parts by iterating and filter only unknown matches.

```js
var regions = [[10, 100], [50, 120], [60, 180], [140, 220]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = regions.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var temp = regions.reduce(function (s, b) {
                var min = Math.max(s[0], b[0]), max = Math.min(s[1], b[1]);
                return min < max ? [min, max] : s;
            }, a),
            key = temp.join('|');

        if (key && !hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = true;
            r.push(temp);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```