# Maximum number of overlapping for each intervals during its range

Tags: algorithm

Given the interval list

[[0,30],[1,5],[6,10],[11,15],[16,20], [21,25]]

Where the first element for each list is the start time, and the second element is the end time.

We see that 0 - 30 overlaps with all other 5 intervals, and all the other interval only overlaps once with another interval, so the maximum number of overlapping is 5.

**Im seeing alot of answers online about finding the minimum number of platform or room needed for conference or train from**

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-platforms-required-railwaybus-station/

http://www.zrzahid.com/maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals/

**But I don't see how those algo applies to this question, as I have tried the algo and they will return 2 for the number of platform and room needed for this example input list, as they will try to find the maximum number of overlap at a particular time, but I want to know the maximum number of overlap that can happen during the entire time interval.**

Below is my brute force approach, and it works, but how can I minimize the runtime to O(nlogn) if possible?

```
function maxNumConflict(intervals) {
    max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        tempMax = 0;
        for (var j = i + 1; j < intervals.length; j++) {
            if (overlap(intervals[i], intervals[j])) {
                tempMax++;
            }
        }
        max = Math.max(tempMax, max);
    }
    return max;
}

function overlap(i1, i2) {
    return ((i1[0] >= i2[0] && i1[0] < i2[1])
         || (i2[0] >= i1[0] && i2[0] < i1[1]));
}
console.log(maxNumConflict(([[0,30],[1,5],[6,10],[11,15],[16,20], [21,25]])));
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Find all disjointed intersections in a set of vertical line segments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318823/find-all-disjointed-intersections-in-a-set-of-vertical-line-segments/40333527#40333527)

Comment: @Redu similar problem it seems, but their algo also runs in O(n^2) time, feel like their algo is way too complicated

Comment: Yes it's a little bit convoluted but that's because what you ask requires more than a simple reducing of intersections. That's also not O(n^2) but something less (the inner reduce only works for the items those haven't intersected previously), though can not make sure about it's time complexity. I would recommend you to read the accepted answer's explanation part and check the last code snippet which is mush easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's fix an interval `[L, R]`. Consider an arbitrary interval `[a, b]`. These two intervals do not overlap if:

1. `b < L` or
2. `a > R`

Note that any interval satisfies at most one of these two conditions. Thus, for the `[L, R]` interval the number of intervals it overlaps with is equal to `N - c1 - c2 - 1`, where `N` is the total number of intervals, `c1` is the number of intervals that satisfy the condition 1 and `c2` is the number of intervals that satisfy the condition 2.

How to find `c1` and `c2` quickly?

If we have a list of all intervals sorted by their right border, `c1` is equal to the position of the first interval (in sorted order) such that its right border is not less than `L`. We can find it using binary search.

Using a binary search over the list of intervals sorted by the left border we can find `c2` (its the number of intervals minus the position of the first interval such that its left border is greater than `R`).

We need to sort two lists of size `N` here and run 2 binary searches over them `N` times. Thus, the time complexity is `O(N * log N)`.

Comment: logically, it makes sense, thanks, let me try to implement the algo

Comment: Smart answer! There are other solutions too (like using a counter and sorting both start and end at the same time), but this one was very logical.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code for the question, the concept works, but didn't check the boundary condition for binary search.

```
// nlogn solution
// Solution is not correct, got error boundary condition on binary search, but the concep works
function findMaxOverlap(times) {

    var arrSize = times.length;
    var max = 0;
    var start = [];
    var end = [];

    // Split the times list into start time list and end time list
    for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        start.push(times[i][0]);
        end.push(times[i][1]);
    }

    // Sort them
    start.sort(compare);
    end.sort(compare)

    // Find the number of overlapping for each interval
    for (var i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, findMaxHelper(start, end, times[i], arrSize));
    }

    return max;

}

function compare(a,b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


function findMaxHelper(startArr, endArr, interval, arrSize) {

    // Num of element that do not overlap with current interval
    var c1 = 0;         // Num of element that has their start time >= current end time 
    var c2 = 0;         // Num of element that has their end time =< current start time 

    c1 = arrSize - binarySearch(startArr, interval[1]);
    c2 = binarySearch(endArr, interval[0]);

    var overlap = arrSize - c1 - c2 - 1;
    return overlap;

}


// Find the index of the element that is >= or =< than time
function binarySearch(arr, time) {

    var low = 0;
    var high = arr.length;
    var mid = high / 2;

    while (low <= high) {
        var mid = Math.round(low + (high - low) / 2);

        if (arr[mid] > time) {  
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (arr[mid] < time) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }  else {
            return mid;
        }

    }
    return Math.round(low + (high - low) / 2);
}
```